# Flutter await is not working with rootBundle.loadString

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

When I calling the following function `getMenu()`, I get the output from below. I thought `await` keyword always wait for the operation to finish, and I should get a string object? Am I missing something here?

```
I/flutter (24112): --- start of menu ---
I/flutter (24112): Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter (24112): --- start end menu ---
```

-

```
 dynamic getMenu(menuPath) async{
    var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString(menuPath);
    print ("--- start of menu ---");
    print (jsonString);
    print ("--- start end menu ---");
    ...
}
```

Comment: C# has a feature with `async-await` where it doesn't actually wait until the awaited resource is actually referenced. I don't know if Dart has the same behavior, but that's a neat little factoid if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run correct and wrong code in DartPad 
You need to `await getMenu()` 
If you do not `await getMenu()` , you will get `Instance of '_Future<String>'` in this example 
example came from https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

correct

```
Future<String> getMenu() async{
  print("before simulateLongJobOrRootBundle");
  var jsonString = await simulateLongJobOrRootBundle();
  print(jsonString);
  print("after jsonString");
  return 'Your jsonString is: $jsonString';
}

Future<String> simulateLongJobOrRootBundle() async{
  print("In simulateLongJobOrRootBundle");
  // Imagine that this function is more complex and slow
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'Large Latte');
}


Future<void>  main() async {
  print('main');
  print(await getMenu());
}
```

[image]

wrong (not result you expected)

```
Future<String> getMenu() async{
  print("before simulateLongJobOrRootBundle");
  var jsonString = await simulateLongJobOrRootBundle();
  print(jsonString);
  print("after jsonString");
  return 'Your jsonString is: $jsonString';
}

Future<String> simulateLongJobOrRootBundle() async{
  print("In simulateLongJobOrRootBundle");
  // Imagine that this function is more complex and slow
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'Large Latte');
}


void main() {
  print('main');
  print(getMenu());
}
```

[image]